# Cron job once a minute for one hour a day

Tags: linux, cron

Is there a way to run a cron job once a minute for an hour every day?

I know I can probably make 60 cron jobs to do this but that would make it difficult if I ever needed to edit the job.

Answer (score 6):

Sure:

```
*/1 4 * * * /home/scripts/my_job.sh
```

That tells it to run every minute during the 4 AM hour.

Comment: @ davidethell. that is cool. I never used it

Comment: Isn't the `/1` redundant?

Comment: Could you explain how the `/1` works. Some other users would like to make it ever '15 minutes for 2 hours' say...

Comment: @DanielBeck, yes, /1 is redundant. * will accomplish the same thing.

Comment: @Pureferret, the /1 says every minute. To make it run every 15 minutes just to /15. For the hours you can specify a two hour range like 2-4. So this would work: */15 2-4 * * *

Answer (score 0):

Why not this?

```
* 4 * * * /home/scripts/my_job.sh
```

The asterisks (*) represent the time parameters for when the script should be executed. In this case, there are five asterisks, which correspond to the following time parameters:

- Minute (0-59)
- Hour (0-23)
- Day of the month (1-31)
- Month (1-12)
- Day of the week (0-6, where 0 represents Sunday)

Since all five asterisks are present, this means that the script will be executed at every minute, every hour, every day of the month, every month, and every day of the week.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).